# What feats can you use with the Telekinesis spell when you use it for range combat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The Mutant CR1 Template lets you choose Telekinesis as an at will Spell Like Ability (SLA). The Telekinesis spell allows for a multi-attack via a volley of Telekinetically thrown objects but subbing the PC Int mod + BAB vs their Str/Dex mod.

> Violent Thrust: Alternatively, the spell energy can be spent in a single round. You can hurl one object or creature per caster level (maximum 15) that are within range and all within 10 feet of each other toward any target within 10 feet per level of all the objects. You can hurl up to a total weight of 25 pounds per caster level (maximum 375 pounds at 15th level).
>
> You must succeed on attack rolls (one per creature or object thrown) to hit the target with the items, using your base attack bonus + your Intelligence modifier (if a wizard) or Charisma modifier (if a sorcerer). Weapons cause standard damage (with no Strength bonus; note that arrows or bolts deal damage as daggers of their size when used in this manner). Other objects cause damage ranging from 1 point per 25 pounds (for less dangerous objects) to 1d6 points of damage per 25 pounds (for hard, dense objects). Objects and creatures that miss their target land in a square adjacent to the target.
>
> Creatures who fall within the weight capacity of the spell can be hurled, but they are allowed Will saves (and spell resistance) to negate the effect, as are those whose held possessions are targeted by the spell.
>
> If a telekinesed creature is hurled against a solid surface, it takes damage as if it had fallen 10 feet (1d6 points).

So far I see Rapid Shot feat applicable as it only a to hit pen of 2 per shot. Are there any ranged feats that can be applied to the use of Telekinesis via a volley attack?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, very few ranged attack feats or other abilities would be applicable to combining with [Telekinesis](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/telekinesis/). The main reasons for this are that Telekinesis requires a Standard Action to activate (either as a spell, or generally as a spell-like or supernatural ability), and it is not a weapon or ranged weapon.

Requiring a standard action to activate means that Telekinesis cannot be combined with any other abilities that require a specific action to be made, such as [Rapid Shot](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/rapid-shot-combat-final/) and [Vital Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/vital-strike-combat-final/).

Telekinesis is also not a weapon, and so will also not combine with feats that require one, including Rapid Shot, [Point Blank Shot](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/point-blank-shot-combat-final/), [Manyshot](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/manyshot-combat-final/) and [Weapon Focus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-focus-combat-final/). [Deadly Aim](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/deadly-aim-combat/) is one of the few ranged combat feats I could think of that would work with this attack form. Note that this is different from spells that use a [Ray](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell), which generally ARE considered weapons.

Comment: Sorry I really should ask this as another question but it still within the subject matter. TK can be used to volley objects even weapons, since this method still needs an attack roll per object....does precision damage like Sneak Attack remain applicable or is this volley like an area effect requiring a reflex save for half damage?

Comment: Wow, threadnomancy! I can't see you'd be able to add precision damage to the viloent thrust, no.